# Create new gradle project

Tags: sql-server, gradle, visual-studio-code

I want to create new Gradle project in vscode, I have problem with default source package, I want it to be src/main/java but when I try to create new project in vscode it recognizes the only src project as a root source directory, so I want to properly start new Gradle project in vscode.

Also I want to have SQL Server driver dependency with Gradle if it is possible. When I injected that dependency, at first try it could not find that driver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the important parts of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

From your description. It looks like you have created a project without any build tools. (In that case, the VS Code Java will recognize 'src' as a source root.)

If you want to create a new Gradle project, maybe you can try some scaffolding tools, such as: [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/), use [Gradle CLI](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications.html), etc...